# Exact conversion from byte[] to String

Tags: java, string, file, arrays

Array byte[] contains a perfect byte by byte copy of a photo, when I try to convert byte[] to String and write to file with it, it fails.

I need to convert to string for send it later through sockets.

My handler per connection have a Socket (sock), PrintWriter (out) and BufferedReader (in), then I associate the Socket to PrintWriter and BufferedReader. With this I send and receive strings with out.println and in.readLine.

How can I fix this?

Test code:

```
// getPhoto() returns byte[]
String photo = new String(getPhoto());

// Create file
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("out1.jpg"));
// This makes imperfect copy of the photo
os.writeBytes(photo);

//This works perfectly basically it copies the image through byte[]
//os.write(getPhoto());

// Close the output stream
os.close();
```

Comment: I do not understand why you are converting a byte array representing a photograph to a String. Please explain.

Comment: Edited, I want it for sending strings through sockets, using println.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Array byte[] contains a perfect byte by byte copy of a photo, when I try to convert byte[] to String and write to file with it, it fails.

Yes. That's because strings are for text, and a photo isn't text. Simply don't convert it to a string. You don't need a `DataOutputStream`, either:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("out1.jpg");
try {
    os.write(getPhoto());
} finally {
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: Instead, use `os.write(getPhoto())`.

Comment: I'm curious, although it's a bad idea: if he converted his byte array to a comma-separated string of values, wrote that to file, read that back into a byte array by parsing the individual values, that'd give him back his image, no?

Comment: @G.Bach: Yes, but it wouldn't be a valid image file without the extra conversion back later on. It would also be rather larger than expected :)

Comment: I need to convert to string, because later I want to send it through sockets (println).

Comment: @Facon: Why would you use `println` with a socket? Sockets are based on *binary* data.

Comment: My handler per connection have a Socket (sock), PrintWriter (out) and BufferedReader (in), then I associate the Socket to PrintWriter and BufferedReader. With this I send and receive strings with out.println and in.readLine.

Comment: @Facon: *Why* have you decided to do everything with text, when you're trying to transfer *binary* data? It's simply a bad idea - as is using `PrintWriter`, which swallows exceptions.

Comment: @JonSkeet Because, they force me to send only strings through sockets, if there are another alternative for doing this, tell me please.

Comment: @Facon: "They"? Who is "they"? If you absolutely *have* to send arbitrary binary data as strings, you should use base64 to encode it first, and then decode it at the other end. See http://iharder.net/base64 for a public domain library for base64 encoding and decoding. But fundamentally this is a strange thing to do when you've got a socket (binary stream) at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Don't load binary data into a String. If it is no tetx, just don't use String